# Confusion about polynomial division

Tags: polynomials, intuition

### $\underline{\text{Motivation}:-}$

The confusion came to my mind while reading a simple question. The question specifically was-

**What should be subtracted from $8x^4+14x^3-2x^2+7x-8$ so that the result is perfectly divisible by $4x^2+3x-2$?**

The answer obviously is the remainder which is $14x-10$ which can be easily calculated through long division. But then I thought what would happen if we used the *Remainder Theorem* which sates that-

**If a polynomial $p(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ then the remainder is $p(a)$**

---

---

### $\underline{\text{Details}:-}$

Now let me explain my confusion. The thing is that to prove the remainder theorem we say that

If $Q$ is the quotient when dividing $p(x)$ by $(x-a)$ and $R$ is the remainder then

$p(x)=(x-a)Q+R$

Putting $x=a$ gives us $R=p(a)$

Now here's where the confusion starts, if instead of specifically $(x-a)$ we take any polynomial $q(x)$ with $\operatorname{deg}q\leq\operatorname{deg}p$ and let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_k$ be the roots of $q(x)$ then obviously the equation-

$p(x)=q(x)Q+R$$-----(\star)$

still holds but now doing the exact thing as before by putting the roots of $q(x)$ in the $x$'s gives us-

$\begin{array} \\R=p(\omega_1)\\R=p(\omega_2)\\{\vdots}\\R=p(\omega_k)\end{array}$

WTF! That makes no sense, well for some cases it may but not for all. There can't be multiple remainders.

---

If we apply the same logic to the problem mentioned at the 'Motivation' part-

The answer is $14x-10$, but according to our above reasoning, the answers are $\frac{1}{4}(7\sqrt{41}-61)$ and $-\frac{1}{4}(61+7\sqrt{41})$ which is again obviously not true.

---

---

### $\underline{\text{My Thoughts}:-}$

Obviously math isn't broken but my reasoning is. I think that the mistake I am doing is of putting the roots in the equation to get the remainder.

There must something much more complicated going on. but then again $(\star)$ is an equation so it should be true for all values for $x$. And that is my confusion.

---

---

### $\underline{\text{My Question}:-}$

Can someone explain what is happening and resolve my confusion? Where are the mistakes?

Comment: There is another easier answer to the main question (what should be subtracted). That is, just subtract $8x^4 + 14x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x - 6$, then the result is $4x^2+3x-2$, which certainly is perfectly divisibly by $4x^2+3x-2$.

Comment: The remainder $R$ is in general not a number, but a polynomial.

Comment: "*The answer obviously is the remainder which is $14x−10$ which can be easily calculated through long division*" $\;-\;$ Try to apply the rest of your argument to this particular example of long division, and you'll find the answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw in the reasoning is that we have assumed that the remainder is a constant as pointed out by @Stefan Albrecht in the comments, this won't always be the case obviously.

The thing is that the remainder theorem works because the polynomial $p(x)$ is being divided by $(x-a)$ so the remainder $R$ has to satisfy $\operatorname{deg}(R)\leq\operatorname{deg}(x-a)$ meaning $\deg R=0$ or simply $R$ is a constant. So when we put $x=a$ in

$p(x)=(x-a)Q+R$,

$R$ is unbothered. Giving us $R=p(a)$

But same reasoning doesn't work for any divisor $q(x)$ as the remainder may itself be a polynomial. So

$p(x)=q(x)Q(x)+R(x)$

Putting $x=\omega_i$ where $\omega_i$ is the root of $q(x)$ gives us-

$R(\omega_i)=p(\omega_i)$

So we don't get the remainder which is $R(x)$ but we get $R$ evaluated at one of the roots of $q(x)$.

For the original question the answer is $R(x)=14x-10$ but the other values are $R(\alpha)$ and $R(\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $4x^2+3x-2$.

That is the resolution and mistake.

However the result $R(\omega_i)=p(\omega_i)$ is pretty neat in itself.